# Update Azure API Management Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We are using Azure API Management for exposing our services to our customers. To create new APIs we import swagger file for our service. If we re-import swagger does Azure API Management delete and re-create APIs? Also is there any downtime for existing customers interacting with the API during swagger updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can import a Swagger file in place in which case the operations are replaced with their new definitions and any policies you have set will be preserved. There should be no downtime.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this such as with Powershell and just supply the swagger document url?

Comment: @starmandeluxe there is tool that makes the deployment of Azure Api Management super easy. it's called dotnet-apim. https://github.com/mirsaeedi/dotnet-apim