# Deployment failed. Correlation ID: x. API with specified name 'x' already exists

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-cli, apim

Im getting this error:
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: x. API with specified name 'x' already exists.

when trying to deploy an api to apim with the az cli.

the command:

```
az apim api import --resource-group x --service-name x --path x --specification-format OpenApi --specification-path x --api-id x --protocols https --service-url x
```

I already have this api deployed in apim but i want to update it what is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [az apim api update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim/api?view=azure-cli-latest#az_apim_api_update) to update an API Management API.

Or call this API [Apis - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/apis/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP) to create new or updates the existing specified API of the API Management service instance.

Or re-import a Swagger file in place in which case the operations are replaced with their new definitions and any policies you have set will be preserved. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023163/update-azure-api-management-configuration).

You could select one method that you are good at.